# Passing Props to Child Component as State in React

Tags: reactjs, state, parent

I have a list which has this Modal component. If a user clicks a certain row in the list, the props within that row are passed down to the `Modal Component`.

When the props are passed to the Modal, I want to call `componentWillReceiveProps` to set the props passed as part of the Modal's state. I do this because props like `title`, `status` and `cost` are eventually going to be controlled inputs that are updated via the Modal's state.

My only problem is `componentWillReceiveProps` is only called once and the props are not passed down to the Modal's state. Is there a way to pass these props to the child component as the state?

I'm using the Modal from [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals)

Parent Component:

```
        <AdditionalPaymentsModal 
          status={'New'}
          id= {null} 
          title={'testong'}
          cost={''} />
```

Child Component:

```
class AdditionalPaymentsModal extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: this.props.showModal,
    };
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
  }

  close() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }

  open() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){  
    console.log("SETTING THE STATE", this.state);
      this.setState({
        id: nextProps.id,
        title:nextProps.title, 
        status: nextProps.status, 
        cost:nextProps.date
    })
  }

render(){
  const {id, title, status, cost} = this.props;

  return (
    <div>​
        <Button
          onClick={this.open}>
          Open
        </Button>
        <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>New Edit Cost</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
          {this.state.title}
          {this.state.id}
          {this.state.cost}
          {this.state.status}
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.close}>Cancel</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: could try putting `this.setState({
        id: props.id,
        title: props.title, 
        status: props.status, 
        cost: props.date
    })` in your `constructor` override, instead of `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: I'd like to add that if the component is receiving these values as props then there should be no reason to have them set to state since you will most likely be passing them back up to the component that grabbed these values when modified. You can do it, but its just redundant since changing the value at the top will automatically update all the children.

Comment: @brycedorn I took the componentWillRecieveProps out and under super(props) of the modal component replaced it with what you used. I didn't seem to generate anything on the modal :/

Comment: are you sure `props` are being passed through correctly? what does a `console.log(props)` below `super(props)` return?

Comment: @brycedorn ok I get this in console.log(props) Object {status: "New", id: null, title: "testong", cost: ""}  but it is still blank in the modal

Comment: well hangon, these things don't even need to be in state. you're already initializing as `const {id, title, status, cost} = this.props` at the start of your `render` function, you can just use these vars now: `<Modal.Body> {title} {id} {cost} {status} </Modal.Body>` will show the props passed in

Comment: @brycedorn AH right,right... Thank you. That seemed to be my mistake!

Comment: yup yw, I'll add it as answer below for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it doesn't look like you're modifying the `props` being passed in; if you're just looking to display them then they don't need to be in `state`.

you already have the props initialized in your `render` function:

`const {id, title, status, cost} = this.props;`

all you need to do is reference these - no need for your constructor to put these in `state`:

`render () {
  ...
  <Modal.Body>
    {title}
    {id}
    {cost}
    {status}
  </Modal.Body>
  ...
}`

Comment: How different would this be if I needed to alter it? Like have a controlled input?

Comment: if, say, you want `cost` to be editable, then yes you would want it to be in `state`. this is something you would want to initialize in your `constructor` (via `this.setState` like your other class functions), and then instead of initializing it in the `render` via props you do so via state: `const { cost } = this.state;`